# Change the way WooCommerce discount sale prices are displayed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Good afternoon friends, I will be brief; I am trying to customize the display of discounted product prices as shown in the following image: 
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Dkmb.jpg)

Now, I have already obtained several codes and I am modifying them to achieve that result. It works well in most products, but in variable products it is something else. Variable products that have a discount stop working, In products that have variations it gives error when a variation has a discount, the product stops working. Could you please help me? I would appreciate!

I have attached the code I have.

```
/* Text before and after the discounted price */
add_filter('woocommerce_format_sale_price', 'filter_function_name', 10, 3);
function filter_function_name($price, $regular_price, $sale_price) {
    $product = new WC_Product(get_the_ID());
    if (!is_admin() && $product->is_type('simple')) {
        $regular_price = 'Before: ' . wc_price($regular_price);
        $sale_price = 'After: ' . wc_price($sale_price);
        $price = $regular_price . ' - ' . $sale_price;
    }
    return $price;
};
/*---------- Showing the saving message  -----------*/
function ts_you_save() {
    global $product;
    if ($product->is_type('simple') || $product->is_type('external') || $product->is_type('grouped')) {
        $regular_price = get_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_regular_price', true);
        $sale_price = get_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_sale_price', true);
        if (!empty($sale_price)) {
            $amount_saved = $regular_price - $sale_price;
            $currency_symbol = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
            $percentage = round((($regular_price - $sale_price) / $regular_price) * 100);
?>
<p style="font-size:24px;color:red;"><b>You Save: <b>$</b><?php echo number_format($amount_saved, 2, '.', '') . " (" . number_format($percentage, 0, '', '') . "%)"; ?></b></p>
<?php
        }
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'ts_you_save', 11);
```

Thank you very much for your time, I await your response :)